# Windows explorer crashes on copying files

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

I have Windows 7 (64bit) and since a few windows updates the following error occurs: When I try to copy a file from one directory to another with the explorer, windows tells me that the explorer hast stopped working. After a few seconds the explorer restarts and works fine until I try to copy something again. Most other operations of the explorer work (e.g. delete, rename, new, open with etc.). None of the solutions I found on the internet work, so any idea to fix it is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

More information:

Specs: Windows 7 Home Premium SP1 64bit (Version 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 Build 7601), i5 cpu, 8gb ram, 1,36 TB HDD (ST31500341AS), usb keyboard, 2x usb mouse (cable+wireless), GeForce GTS 240 gpu (ask if you need more)

Antivirus: Norton Security

What I tried: Disabled shell extensions, disabled all third party services, registry cleanup, checked harddrive for damaged sectors, defragmentized harddrive, virus scan, ad/malware scan, system file scan

Comment: Does it happen in Safe Mode?

Comment: @Ramhound In safe mode the problem does not occur.

Comment: You have software installed that is causing this.  You will have to determine which software,when started with your pc, causs this problem

Comment: @Ramhound I just removed all autostart entries and disabled all non microsoft services and the problem still occurs. Does this mean a system program is damaged? Or will it help to deinstall all recently installed software?

Comment: If you booted to safe mode, and it does not happen, you missed something.

Comment: look if you can generate a crash dump: http://pastebin.com/WACz5GBU if yes, share the dmp, I'll analyze it

Comment: @magicandre1981  http://www.filedropper.com/explorerexe6920dmp

Comment: ok, I posted what I saw from the dmp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Looking at the crashdump with Windbg.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Windows/Hardware/ff538058(v=vs.85).aspx) (which is part of the Debugging Tool for windows/Windows SDK) shows that `psdprotect.dll` from `EgisTec MyWinLocker 3` causes the crash:

```
0:048> !analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Exception Analysis                                   *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************


DUMP_CLASS: 2

DUMP_QUALIFIER: 400

CONTEXT:  (.ecxr)
rax=0000000080004005 rbx=0000000009f269f8 rcx=0000000000000000
rdx=0000026500560124 rsi=0000000000000048 rdi=0000000000000000
rip=00000000100012db rsp=000000000c6eeb80 rbp=0000000009cbb628
 r8=0000000009d0a250  r9=0000000000000002 r10=0000000000000000
r11=0000026400500123 r12=00000000ffffffff r13=0000000003c02220
r14=0000000000000000 r15=0000000000000001
iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na po nc
cs=0033  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00010206
psdprotect+0x12db:
00000000`100012db 488b01          mov     rax,qword ptr [rcx] ds:00000000`00000000=????????????????
Resetting default scope

FAULTING_IP: 
psdprotect+12db
00000000`100012db 488b01          mov     rax,qword ptr [rcx]

EXCEPTION_RECORD:  (.exr -1)
ExceptionAddress: 00000000100012db (psdprotect+0x00000000000012db)
   ExceptionCode: c0000005 (Access violation)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 2
   Parameter[0]: 0000000000000000
   Parameter[1]: 0000000000000000
Attempt to read from address 0000000000000000

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  NULL_POINTER_READ

PROCESS_NAME:  explorer.exe

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - Die Anweisung in 0x%08lx verweist auf Speicher 0x%08lx. Der Vorgang %s konnte nicht im Speicher durchgef hrt werden.

EXCEPTION_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - Die Anweisung in 0x%08lx verweist auf Speicher 0x%08lx. Der Vorgang %s konnte nicht im Speicher durchgef hrt werden.

EXCEPTION_CODE_STR:  c0000005

WATSON_BKT_MODVER:  3.1.72.0

MODULE_VER_PRODUCT:  MyWinLocker

APP:  explorer.exe

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 10.0.10586.567 amd64fre

THREAD_ATTRIBUTES: 
OS_LOCALE:  DEU

PROBLEM_CLASSES: 


NULL_POINTER_READ
    Tid    [0x1ea0]
    Frame  [0x00]: psdprotect


STACK_TEXT:
00 ntdll!NtWaitForMultipleObjects
01 KERNELBASE!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx
02 kernel32!WaitForMultipleObjectsExImplementation
03 kernel32!WerpReportFaultInternal
04 kernel32!WerpReportFault
05 kernel32!BasepReportFault
06 kernel32!UnhandledExceptionFilter
07 ntdll! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'
08 ntdll!_C_specific_handler
09 ntdll!RtlpExecuteHandlerForException
0a ntdll!RtlDispatchException
0b ntdll!KiUserExceptionDispatch
0c psdprotect
0d psdprotect
0e shell32!CFSDropTargetHelper::_MoveCopyHIDA
0f shell32!CFSDropTargetHelper::_Drop
10 shell32!CFSDropTargetHelper::s_DoDropThreadProc
11 shlwapi!WrapperThreadProc
12 kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk
13 ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart


00000000`10000000 00000000`10026000   psdprotect   (export symbols)       psdprotect.dll
    Loaded symbol image file: psdprotect.dll
    Image path: C:\Program Files (x86)\EgisTec\MyWinLocker 3\x64\psdprotect.dll
    Image name: psdprotect.dll
    Browse all global symbols  functions  data
    Timestamp:        Thu Aug 06 19:13:12 2009 (4A7B0F28)
    CheckSum:         00029240
    ImageSize:        00026000
    File version:     3.1.72.0
    Product version:  3.1.72.0
    File flags:       0 (Mask 3F)
    File OS:          4 Unknown Win32
    File type:        2.0 Dll
    File date:        00000000.00000000
    Translations:     0409.04e4
    CompanyName:      Egis Technology Inc.
    ProductName:      MyWinLocker
    InternalName:     PSDProtect.dll
    OriginalFilename: PSDProtect.dll
    ProductVersion:   3.1.72.0
    FileVersion:      3.1.72.0
    FileDescription:  PSD DragDrop Protection
    LegalCopyright:   Copyright (C)2008 Egis Technology Inc. All rights reserved.
```

Update or remove the program.

Comment: Thank you very much for your affords! I uninstalled the program and now the explorer is working again.

Comment: nice to hear this.